# Modfying DOM elements involved in a jQuery function

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

Specifically, drag and drop using jQuery.

```
                        $(".note").droppable({
                            drop: function () {

                            }
                        });
```

How do I get the DOM element that:

1) Is being dragged/dropped?

2) Is being dropped onto?

Follow up question: Any suggestions on how I could have answered this question on my own?

Comment: Both about the draggable and droppable plugins and  jQuery's general notes, yeah. Web development is a little intimidating to me right now since I'm coming off years of nothing but applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you hook the `drop` event of the draggable with a function accepting two arguments, `event` and `ui`, then `this` is the raw DOM element of the droppable the draggable was dropped on, and `ui.draggable` is the draggable.

From [the docs on the `drop` event](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#event-drop):

> This event is triggered when an accepted draggable is dropped 'over' (within the tolerance of) this droppable. In the callback, `$(this)` represents the droppable the draggable is dropped on. `ui.draggable` represents the draggable.

There they've said the droppable is `$(this)`, but that's because they assume you want a jQuery instance wrapped around it. `this` will be the raw DOM element.

E.g.:

```
$("your selector here").droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        // this = raw DOM element of droppable
        // $(this) = creates jQuery wrapper around the DOM element
        // `ui.draggable` = draggable

        // Let's make the draggable red, and the droppable blue:
        ui.draggable.css("color", "red");
        $(this).css("color", "blue");
    }
});
```

[Here's a live copy](http://jsbin.com/agofad) one of their examples with the above in action.

Comment: Thanks friend. I'm still not really clear on why the arguments of that function are (event, ui), but this certainly works.  I actually read this in the docs but couldn't get it working because I didn't have ui defined in the scope and kept getting javascript errors.

Comment: @Jeremy: The arguments are `event` and `ui` just because that's how the jQuery UI library defines them. :-) It's just how they've defined the API. Nearly all "event" style callbacks in jQuery UI (not jQuery, jQuery UI) are given those two arguments; the contents of the `ui` object vary depending on what the object is that the event relates to (draggable, droppable, dialog, autocompleter, etc.), but those are usually it and it will be documented -- sometimes subtly -- in the jQuery UI documentation.